# How to convert Array String to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any best way to convert String to Array.

I am using Spring mvc and calling ajax from javascript and getting String live

```
var result = "[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]"
```

I want to convert this String in array like

```
var resultArray = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]
```

and when I find length i want to get 2

Comment: what will be the actual values in the array and its format

Comment: this is not a valid 2 dimensional array representation in java

Comment: @gurvinder372 why not?

Comment: The strings should be in double quotes, see http://json.org for correct format.

Comment: @Saba in java it is {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}

Comment: @gurvinder372 I guess that he used a,b,c,d.. like that just as example of generic values

Comment: If this is the result of an AJAX call and your returning JSON why not set the headers for the request and response correctly so it will parse it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Earlier I was returning a List of List like

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

So it was getting the error in the jQuery function during JSON parsing because I was getting "`[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]`" and not the double quotes ("a"). Then I changed the back-end code and it is returning JsonArray of JsonArray like `[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]]`, and now I am able to parse JSON.

```
JSONArray outerJsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONArray innerJsonArray = new JSONArray();

innerJsonArray.put("a");
innerJsonArray.put("b");
innerJsonArray.put("c");
outerJsonArray.put(innerJsonArray);

innerJsonArray.put("d");
innerJsonArray.put("e");
innerJsonArray.put("f");
outerJsonArray.put(innerJsonArray);
```

and returning `outerJsonArray.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSON.parse

```
var resultArray = JSON.parse('[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]]');
```

You can get the size using resultArray.length

Check this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp

Of course this string **"[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]"** cannot work becouse is not a correct JSON string, each word must be between double quotes

Comment: Don't forget for polyfill for old browsers: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: alert(JSON.parse("[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]"))   gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a(…)"

Comment: @RadekPech, What old browsers you want to support, IE6 I guess??

Comment: @Oxi  a, b, c, d, e, f  are just example of values, of course it does not work, OP used those just as example of what he's trying to do

Comment: @Saba  "[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]"  is a string live (exactly from the question). he didn't say its JSON string. its just some random string

Answer (score 0):

The Only Way for you if your result everytime has a "].[" ...

Then and ONLY then -> Will This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joel_Jaun/qs72c4kx/) work for you.

Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

JS(With JQUery V. 1.11:

```
var result = "[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]"

var splitter = result.split('],[');
var arr = [];

$.each(splitter, function(i, e){
    var arrElement = e;
  while(arrElement.indexOf(']') > -1){
    arrElement = arrElement.replace(']', '');
  }
  while(arrElement.indexOf('[') > -1){
    arrElement = arrElement.replace('[', '');
  }

  arr.push(arrElement);

});

$('.a').text(arr[0]);
$('.b').text(arr[1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSON.parse("[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]") or eval,but I recommend the JSON.parse

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend using eval? In the case where a, b, c, d, e, and f are actual identifiers, eval will give the correct answer. While just using JSON.parse will fail without quoting the characters or do some more complex concatenation.